# Do we really need to use the assumption to show that $\phi$ is well defined. (Serge Lang Calculus of Several Variables)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, potential-theory

I am reading "Calculus of Several Variables 3rd Edition" by Serge Lang.

Do we really need to use the assumption to show that $\phi$ is well defined.

[image]

Comment: If the condition involving the integral on the circle were not satisfied this definition of the potential would be ill-defined and in particular *discontinuous*. Consider what happens as you compute the potential along the circle: at $(1,0)$ you would set the potential to zero, and as you compute the potential in the anti-clock wise direction you would end up with a nonzero value ($\int_C F\neq0$) of the potential when approaching $(1,0)$ after a near full turn. Hence your potential would be ill defined or at the very least discontinuous.

Comment: I think Lang specifies a unique path from $(1,0)$ to $X$.

Comment: Since $\phi$ is defined using a specific path of integration, it is well-defined. The assumptions will, however, be needed to show that $\phi$ is differentiable and its gradient is $F$. Indeed, as @Olivier Bégassat pointed out, without the assumption about the integral along the unit circle, $\phi$ would be discontinuous. And without the assumption about the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$, the gradient wouldn't be $F$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olivier gives the answer in his comment, but you seem to have missed the point. It is true that $\phi$ is well-defined for all $X\neq0$ *not on the circle*, because Lang specifies a unique path from $(1,0)$ to $X$. And obviously $\phi((1,0))=0$.

But consider points of the form $X_\epsilon=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for $\theta=2\pi-\epsilon$, where $0<\epsilon<2\pi$. We'd like $\phi$ to be differentiable, so we need it to be continuous; hence $\phi(X_\epsilon)$ should approach $\phi((1,0))=0$ as $\epsilon\to0$. The assumption guarantees this.

Comment: symplectomorphic, Thank you very much for your answer.